# Webcam not working on Macbook Pro 13"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, camera, webcam

At some point this year I noticed that my camera was not working. (Skype, Google, Facetime)

I tried this https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2090

But under devices for Camera it says no devices found.

Mac OS 10.10.4

Comment: You mean in the About this Mac it does not show it ? FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in):

Comment: Probably it's broken or internally disconnected.

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes this is correct, it does not show any hardware. It is a 2012 Macbook Pro 13"

Comment: Open system profiler/system information form the utilities folder (in the applications folder). Under hardware there should be a category "camera". Does it show you anything there?

Comment: Hi Kevin, it shows no camera right now.

Answer (score 15):

It might be some VDCAssistant programs using it.

Try this ,Open a terminal window and type the command below.

```
sudo killall VDCAssistant
```

This will kill all other programs and you will be able to use your camera again.

Comment: Just run the command and it works in Skype again :). Thanks.